# String cut, trim at first space character

Tags: php, string

i'm trying to select values from the database and place each and every one on a separate **text input field**. my code works properly, however, when i tried to display a string on a text field, the string is **cut** or trimmed on its very first **space** character. for example:

```
value #1: "my-picture.jpg"

value #2: "my name"
```

if i were to place the two values above and insert them inside a text field, the output would be like this:

```
value #1: my-picture.jpg
value #2: my
```

this is the code i'm working on:

```
<?php 
$counter = 0;
while ($newArray = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo "
<input type='text' value=".$newArray['my_picture'].">
<input type='text' value=".$newArray['my_name'].">
";
?>
```

What is wrong? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to quote your values in your HTML form:

```
echo '
<input type="text" value="'.$newArray['my_picture'].'">
<input type="text" value="'.$newArray['my_name'].'">
';
```

Also for good measure it would be a good idea to use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) or [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on the values in your variables to encode special characters:

```
echo '<input type="text" value="' . htmlentities($newArray['my_picture']) . '">
      <input type="text" value="' . htmlentities($newArray['my_name']) . '">';
```

Comment: @user1328840 If your (X)HTML is not doing what you expect it to, [try validating it](http://validator.w3.org/)...

Answer (score 2):

Try viewing the source.. That says:

```
<input type='text' value=the content of your variable>
```

Where 'the content of your variable' needs to be surrounded by quotes, naturally. So; change it into:

```
<?php 
$counter = 0;
while ($newArray = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<input type="text" value="' . $newArray['my_picture'] . '">';
    echo '<input type="text" value="' . $newArray['my_name'] . '">';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround your value with quotes. Something like

```
echo "
  <input type='text' value='".$newArray['my_picture']."'>
  <input type='text' value='".$newArray['my_name']."'>
";
```